# how to get read data from barcode scaner using bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

I have a problem that took me at least two weeks without a solution.

Can anyone help me effect  .I developed an android app that has to connect with a **barcode scanner** peyote the connection with the scanner via **Bluetooth** .

it is done very well but my problem is at the **level of the data recovery** that comes from the scanner which is the barcode.

> Here is my Code :

```
private class ServerBluetoothClass extends Thread {

        private BluetoothServerSocket bluetoothSocket;
        private BluetoothSocket socket=null;

        public ServerBluetoothClass(){
            try {
                bluetoothSocket= bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(APP_NAME,MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run(){

            while (socket==null){
                try {

                    Message message=Message.obtain();
                    message.what=STATE_CONNECTING;
                    handler.sendMessage(message);

                    socket=bluetoothSocket.accept();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    Message message=Message.obtain();
                    message.what=STATE_CONNECTION_FAILED;
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                }

                if (socket!=null){

                    Message message=Message.obtain();
                    message.what=STATE_CONNECTED;
                    handler.sendMessage(message);

                    sendReceive=new SendReceive(socket);
                    sendReceive.start();

                    //code after

                    break;

                }
            }

        }

        // Closes the client socket and causes the thread to finish.
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the client socket", e);
            }
        }

    }
```